# roots of multi-variable polynomials and extension fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am teaching a course in (standard single-variable) Galois theory and the following, presumably naive, question occurred to me:

> Given a finite collection of polynomial equations in a finite number of variables with coefficients in some field $K$ such that they have a finite number of solutions, are the coordinates of the solutions necessarily algebraic over $K$?

Since googling *multi-variable Galois theory* brought up very little except [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81209/galois-theory-for-polynomials-in-several-variables), I assume the answer is *no*, but I would love to know something about it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me state your question more precisely (since you don't say where these solutions are, if they aren't in an algebraic extension of $K$):

> Suppose $f_1, \dots f_m$ are polynomials in $K[x_1, \dots x_n]$ such that the system $f_1 = \dots = f_m = 0$ has finitely many solutions in any field $L$ containing $K$. Are these solutions always algebraic over $K$?

The answer is yes, which you can see as follows. By [Noether normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma), the ring $R = K[x_1, \dots x_n]/(f_1, \dots f_m)$ is a finite integral extension of some free subring $S = K[y_1, \dots y_d]$. If $L$ is any infinite and algebraically closed field containing $K$, it follows that there are infinitely many $L$-points (homomorphisms $R \to L$ of $K$-algebras, or solutions over $L$ of our system of equations) unless $d = 0$.

If $d = 0$, then $R$ is finite-dimensional over $K$, from which it follows that there are at most finitely many $L$-points for any $L$, whose coordinates must be algebraic. This is because, since $R$ is finite-dimensional, for any $x_i$ there is some linear dependence among the monomials $\{ 1, x_i, x_i^2, \dots \}$, so each $x_i$ satisfies a polynomial over $K$.

In general, there is a subject one might call "multivariable Galois theory," but people usually call it "algebraic geometry" (over non-algebraically closed fields), or more specifically "Galois descent."

---

**Edit:** Here's a lower-tech but longer argument using only transcendence degree. We'll prove the contrapositive: if the system has a solution over some field $L$ whose coordinates are not algebraic over $K$, then it has infinitely many solutions over some other field.

Suppose $(\ell_1, \dots \ell_n) \in L^n$ is a transcendental solution over $L$, and let $D$ be the $K$-subalgebra of $L$ generated by the coordinates. ($D$ is a quotient of $R$ above, but unlike $R$ it is an integral domain.) We'll attempt to construct infinitely many new solutions over some other field $L''$ by writing down infinitely many $K$-algebra homomorphisms $D \to L''$.

Let $L'$ be the fraction field of $D$. By hypothesis, $L'$ has positive transcendence degree over $K$. Hence $L'$ is an algebraic extension of a transcendental extension of $K$. Since $D$ is finitely generated as a $K$-algebra, $L'$ is a finite algebraic extension of a finite transcendental extension $K(t_1, \dots t_d)$ of $K$. Let $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_k$ be the finitely many elements generating $L'$ as an algebraic extension of $K(t_1, \dots t_d)$.

By construction, we can write each $\ell_i$ as a polynomial in the $\alpha_i$ with coefficients in $K(t_1, \dots t_d)$. We will now attempt to write down infinitely many $K$-algebra homomorphisms $g : D \to L''$ for some third field $L''$ containing $K$. We will do this by picking values for $g(\alpha_i), g(t_i)$ such that each $\ell_i$ continues to be well-defined; equivalently, we just need to arrange for the denominators of each term of each $\ell_i$ to be nonzero. An easy way to do this is to take $L''$ to be the algebraic closure of $K(s_1, s_2, \dots)$. Then we can send $g(t_i)$ to any $s_j$, and send $g(\alpha_i)$ to various roots of various polynomials, which exist since $L''$ is algebraically closed. If there are infinitely many $s_j$ then there are infinitely many such homomorphisms, as desired.

(Other arguments are possible at this last step if $K = \mathbb{Q}, L = \mathbb{C}$. Then we can take $L'' = \mathbb{C}$. We need to avoid the zero sets of a finite set of polynomials in the $t_i$, but there are many ways to see that there are infinitely many ways to do this: for example, the zero sets of polynomials have measure zero.)

(Note how much work we have to do to cobble together a substitute for Noether normalization!)

Comment: can i ask 1 more question: is this the lowest tech answer that's possible?(there are quite a lot of words in it that I have heard before, but have no idea what they mean).

Comment: @anthony: the second half of the argument can be replaced by something lower tech; I'll edit the simpler argument in. If you were willing to be more specific about the fields involved (say $K$ a number field, $L = \mathbb{C}$) maybe the first half can be made lower tech as well.

Comment: Thanks again! I really had in mind $K=\mathbb Q$, but this struck me as a fairly obvious question (it arose from a discussion with a colleague about an integration formula due to Gauss), and I was embarrassed to have no idea about the answer.

Comment: Okay, so let me specialize to $K = \mathbb{Q}, L = \mathbb{C}$. The point of the Noether normalization argument is just that the scheme $\text{Spec } R$ either has positive or zero dimension; in the first case it has infinitely many complex points, and in the second case it looks like a finite set of points as a scheme (some of these points may be "fat," such as $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Q}[t]/t^2$). You need some tool which is powerful enough to exhibit some version of this dichotomy, and Noether normalization is maybe the second simplest such tool. (The simplest is transcendence degree, but...

Comment: ...the difficulty here is that we can't assume that $R$ is an integral domain, so we can't form its fraction field.)

Comment: @anthony: hmm, never mind, I think an argument using only transcendence degree is possible, but it's a bit longer.

Comment: @anthony: I've edited in the argument using transcendence degree.

Comment: I'm reminded of a comment by Miles Reid, who said (I think) that the level of questions that AG people are asked by non-AG people is analogous to the level questions asked by non-mathematicians of mathematicians.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, It is a nice answer. But I am confused with the matter that $\text{the elements of $K$ are scalars while the solutions of $f_1,f_2, \cdots,f_m$ are $n$-tuple vectors,}$ $\text{ so how does these $n$-tuple vectors generate the extension $L$ of $K$} ?$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, can you please respond my comment ?